# Convert Url/Path to Json with Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, function, path

I recently built a little node program able to console.log all the files of a precise path. 
The result I get from this function looks like this for instance :

```
/Volumes/TimeCapsule/movies/movie1
 movie1.mp4
/Volumes/TimeCapsule/movies/movie2
 movie2.mp4
/Volumes/TimeCapsule/movies/movie3
 movie3.mp4
```

Now my question is:  how can I manage to convert each of this path to JSON so I could be able for instance to display all the files of the movie folder in a single html page ?

I would like to have something like this :

```
{ "Volumes": {
             "TimeCapsule": {
                            "Movies":{
                                    "Title": "Movie1"
                                    "Title": "Movie2"
                                    "Title": "Movie3"
                                   }
                            }
           }

}
```

Thank you in advance.

By the way here is my walk function :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var walk = function (currentPath) {
 console.log(currentPath);
 var files = fs.readdirSync(currentPath); //Returns array of filename in currenpath
 for (var i in files) {
   var currentFile = currentPath + '/' + files[i];
   var stats = fs.statSync(currentFile);
   if (stats.isFile()) {
   console.log(currentFile.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')););
   }
  else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
         walk(currentFile);
       }
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I really wanted, I even added a path section so I can have an access to the path of each single file :

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('mypath')

 function walk(path) {
     var stats = fs.lstatSync(mypath),
       info = {
        path: mypath,
        Title: path.basename(mypath)
    };

if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    info.type = "folder";
    info.children = fs.readdirSync(filename).map(function(child) {
        return walk(mypath + '/' + child);
    });
} else {
    info.type = "file";
}

return info;
}


console.log(walk('/Users/maximeheckel/Desktop'));
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here we go:

```
var fs = require( "fs" );
function walk( path, arr ) {
    var ret = {};
    arr = Array.isArray( arr ) ? arr : [];

    fs.readdirSync( path ).forEach(function( item ) {
        var current = path + "/" + item;
        var stats = fs.statSync( current );
        if ( stats.isFile() ) {
            arr.push( current );
        } else if ( stats.isDirectory() ) {
            walk( current, arr );
        }
    });

    arr.forEach(function( item ) {
    var i, len;
        item.split( "/" ).reduce(function( obj, path, i, parts ) {
            if ( ( i + 1 ) === parts.length ) {
                obj.Title = path;
            } else {
                obj[ path ] = obj[ path ] || {};
                return obj[ path ];
            }
        }, ret);
    });

    return ret;
}
```

this was not tested, but maybe it give you some ideas on how to do it.

Comment: It looks like it works but I have an issue. Your walk function only puts in the title section the first file it founds and then explores another folder. I can't have the full content of a folder but I will simply add some restrictions to my project ( such as putting only .mp4 files into one folder and nothing more ) Thank you for your help !

Comment: I don't get exactly what I want, here's an example :                                   
    
    {
      Volume{},
      timeCapsule{},
      movies{},
      movie1{ Title: 'movie1.mp4'}
}

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer. See if the new code does what you want :)

Comment: Almost right I will try to fix your code because it says something like { '': { Volumes: { timeCapsule: [Object] } } }